# TDD iOS tutorial

Tags: ios, ios5, tdd

Hi I looking for really good tutorial for iOS TDD, would you please help me!

what is the best iOS TDD book, blog --> tutorial
(I had different research on google but since I don't have enough knowledge about " iOS TDD " I don't know which one is the best)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you perhaps list some of the ones you found?

Comment: My iOS coding blog has a TDD category: http://qualitycoding.org/tdd/

Comment: I thought this book was pretty good http://www.amazon.com/Test-iOS-Apps-UI-Automation/dp/1937785521/ref=pd_sim_b_44?ie=UTF8&refRID=1P3AHF1VK3VH6590P3J8

Answer (score 8):

There are many stuff about TDD on iOS available on the web..

If you choose using GHUnit, I recommend you using XCode's template available here: https://github.com/zenkimoto/ghunit-ocmock-xcode4-template

and if you use ARC, I recommend changing your GHUnitTestMain.m with this:

http://hataewon.tumblr.com/post/17502311021/continuous-integration-for-cocoa

At last, I recommend the book Test Driven iOS Development from Graham Lee [http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-iOS-Development-Developers-Library/dp/0321774183](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774183)

(Sorry, as a new user I could not post more than two links)

Comment: The first link now points to a spam website.

Comment: that's not what I experienced following the first link

Comment: Just for an update on how to do Unit Testing on Xcode 5 using XCTest framework : http://youtube.com/watch?v=8cpEIik-FZM